# Cassandra routing key not set due to ArgumentException: Column column_aliases not found

Tags: c#, .net, cassandra, datastax

When using method from Cassandra.Session:

```
/// <summary>
/// Prepares the provided query string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cqlQuery">cql query to prepare</param>
PreparedStatement Prepare(string cqlQuery);
```

internally an exception is thrown:

```
Message: A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Cassandra.dll
Additional information: Column column_aliases not found

Cassandra.dll!Cassandra.Row.GetValue<string>(string name)   Unknown
Cassandra.dll!Cassandra.KeyspaceMetadata.GetTableMetadata(string tableName) Unknown
Cassandra.dll!Cassandra.Metadata.GetTable(string keyspace, string tableName)    Unknown
Cassandra.dll!Cassandra.Session.SetPrepareTableInfo(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Cassandra.PreparedStatement> t) Unknown
Cassandra.dll!Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.DoNext<Cassandra.PreparedStatement,Cassandra.PreparedStatement>(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Cassandra.PreparedStatement> task, System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Cassandra.PreparedStatement>,Cassandra.PreparedStatement> next) Unknown
Cassandra.dll!Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.Continue<Cassandra.PreparedStatement,Cassandra.PreparedStatement>.AnonymousMethod__9(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Cassandra.PreparedStatement> innerTask)   Unknown
```

Thus, routing keys for prepared query aren't set and I have to set them manually. Here is the message for the log:

```
Cassandra.Session: 08-18-2015 14:21:38.367 +02:00 #ERROR: There was an error while trying to retrieve table metadata for mykeyspace.mytable.
System.ArgumentException: Column column_aliases not found
in Cassandra.Row.GetValue[T](String name)
in Cassandra.KeyspaceMetadata.GetTableMetadata(String tableName)
in Cassandra.Metadata.GetTable(String keyspace, String tableName)
in Cassandra.Session.SetPrepareTableInfo(Task`1 t)
Cassandra.Session: 08-18-2015 14:21:38.369 +02:00 : Routing information could not be set for query "INSERT INTO mytable (x, y, z, k, a) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

How to fix that?

I'm using:

- Cassandra C# Driver version 2.5.2
- Cassandra Datastax Community version 2.2.0

Comment: Looks like a driver issue, could you post a ticket here: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/projects/CSHARP/issues detailing the query and schema you are preparing and executing

Comment: I realized that you are using driver version 2.5.2, I posted an answer to recommend you to use the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use v2.6+ of the DataStax C# Driver that fully supports Apache Cassandra 2.2.

[Read more in the DataStax C# Driver v2.6 blog post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/csharp-driver-cassandra-2-2)

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue. That must have been commit between 2.5.2 and 2.6.